# html textfield, in android web browser, is moving vertically when scrolling

Tags: mobile, web, textfield

I'm making an simple mobile web page and i put the textinput on the page and many elements also.
so to see bottom element, the scrolling needed. but when i scrolled my page, i found my textinput moving together abnormally.

below image is that i captured when the error occurred in my android web browser.
first one is original textinput and green box is error occurred.

[image]

please let me know how to fix it..

Answer (score 0):

self answer.

It is occurred cause it's content height. 
I fixed it by change content height: auto; in css :)